# How do you factor f(x)= $x^3-3x^2+4?$ I have tried, but don't understand how to factor if value $a \times c= 4$ while value $b =-3.$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Factor $f(x)= x^3-3x^2+4.$ Then find all zeros of the polynomial.

Comment: What are $a,b,c?$

Comment: a=1 from the 1 in front of x^3, b=-3 from -3x^2, and c=4.

Comment: Hint: If (x - r) is a factor of a polynomial with integer coefficients, and r is an integer, then the constant is divisible by r or by -r.

4 has very few factors, so simply guessing those factors and trying long division or synthetic division will get you an answer

Comment: Your question does not currently meet the quality standards for Math SE.  Please take a look at the topic [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), and follow the advice there on asking questions.  You can use the "Edit" button to improve your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
x^3-3x^2+4 
&= x^3+x^2-4x^2+4 \\
&= x^2(x+1)-4(x+1)(x-1) \\
&= (x+1)(x^2 - 4x + 4) \\
&= (x+1)(x-2)^2 \end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $x +1$ divides the cubic evenly.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $x = 2$ is a zero. Can you continue ....?